# Please tell me how to import video files that I put in the internal storage using Unity on my Android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, internal-storage

I am making Android app using Unity. I'm trying to play a video using VideoPlayer. I put several mp4 files in a specific folder in the Android device's internal storage, and I change only the videoname, so I want to load the mp4 file there. Below is the code I wrote.

```
String url = "/sdcard/Download/VR Video/" + videoName;
videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.Url;
videoPlayer.url = url;
videoPlayer.Prepare();
```

Comment: are you unable to get video from sdcard? right ?

Comment: I can not get video from sdcard